# Como remover uma classe css usando jquery em apenas uma tela? não está funcionando

Tags: css-transições

Eu quero usar essa classe em todo layout do site, menos na tela principal porque lá tem uma imagem que que precisa ficar no topo, ou seja(padding-top: 0px).

Classe que preciso remover em uma tela:

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Função jQuery que criei para fazer isso e não deu certo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#intro").removeClass("body");
});
```

OBS: intro é o id da imagem que no topo(0px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando uma palavra reservada para uma classe, o correto é você adicionar um ponto no inicio da declaração, pq o css está interpretando como se fosse o elemento body do HTML.

Faça isso que deve funcionar, note que eu só acrescentei um `.`(ponto) no início.

```
.body {
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Ramiressss!! não estudo css, não iria imaginar que fosse apenas isso

Comment: Por nada. É bom saber que podemos ajudar de alguma forma.